# I have got some problems with adding up numbers from a .txt file

Tags: c++, fstream

I got a homework in school and I have done it but the result is not exactly what I wanted.

The task is to get sums from a text file with the following rules:

- the first column contains numbers
- the second is a 0/1 boolean (the separating character is space)
- whenever the bool is true in continuous lines, the programme should add up the numbers

The .txt file looks like this: 
**Input:**

20 1

30 1

40 0

50 1

60 1

**Desired Output:**
50

110

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string line;
double number;
double sum;
int boolean;
sum = 0;

ifstream homework;
homework.open("homework.txt");
    while (!homework.eof())
    {
        homework >> number >> boolean;

        if (boolean == 1)
        {
            sum += number;          
        }
    }

cout << sum << endl;

homework.close();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I wanted the code to print out 50 and 110 (because there is a line with a false boolean) but instead, the code printed 160 (so it summed up all lines with true boolean).

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, when you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) make sure it doesn't contain any unrelated errors (yours do). Then also please read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: your "boolean" var don't seam to be declared anywhere, I'm suprised your code would compile at all.

Comment: where is boolean declared?

Comment: I have it in my code just forgot to write it here sorry.

Comment: You need to reset sum to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you do not output until the file has been iterated completely, so you see the total sum, and not the sum after each `false` boolean value. If you want sub totals every time you encounter a boolean `false` you need to add something to your loop:

```
while (homework >> number >> boolean)
{
    if (boolean)
    {
        sum += number;          
    }
    else
    {
        cout << sum << endl;
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

Btw. how is your boolean variable `boolean` declared, does your code even compile? I have changed the check in my sample (removed the `== 1`).

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to write it in. Besides that, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the line `cout << sum << endl;` in an else case inside the while loop, as well as reset the sum.

Something like this should do:

```
while (!homework.eof())
{
    homework >> number >> boolean;

    if (boolean == 1)
    {
        sum += number;          
    }
    else
    {
        cout << sum << endl;
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even better: `std::cout << sum << `'\n'`;`. You don't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does.

Answer (score 0):

You have many choices, one could be:

1st one: define the boolean variable as exactly that (a bool variable) and compare those against a true false

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    bool boolean;
    double number{ 0 };
    double sum{ 0 };

    ifstream homework;
    homework.open("hw.txt");
    while (!homework.eof())
    {
        homework >> number >> boolean;

        if (boolean)
        {
            sum += number;
        }
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    homework.close();

    return 0;
}
```

to stop the while when a false is found you can use a break

```
    if (boolean)
    {
        sum += number;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: What would he benefit from using a string? an integer is faster, and he already has it, why should he change it to a string?

Comment: Ok, but still none of your proposals fixes the problem the OP has, which is showing the total after each time a false value occurs. :)